# Are there async abstract base classes in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, abstract-class

I need to implement a mapping type in an async Python 3 application (I'm using tornadoweb but it could be any event loop.)

I would like to take advantage the `collections.abc` package. The mapping should be using mongodb (more specifically, Motor https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ ) for storing key-value pairs.

My problem is that MutableMapping has no aync version. For example:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
class AsyncMongoMap(MutableMapping):
    async def __getitem__(self, key):
        return await self.collection.find_one(dict(key=key))["value"]
```

In theory, all abstract methods (`__getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, __iter__ and __len__`) could be async methods, returning awaitable objects. That would allow me to await for them, e.g.:

```
await some_map["key"]
```

The problem is that `__getitem__` cannot be an async method. I can still return an awaitable from it, but that won't help. It is not compatible with `MutableMapping`. For example, the `get()` method expects that **getitem** will raise KeyError when the key is not in the mapping. So if `__getitem__` returns an awaitable, then `get()` simply won't work (and it cannot be awaited for anyway). So this will never work:

```
await some_map.get("key", "default_value")
```

A good solution would be to use `collections.abc.AsyncMutableMapping`, if there was such thing. I could write my own version, but it seems like a bad idea. This is a general problem of not having async versions of abstract base classes.

Is there a "best practice" for this? Should I write and publish a new package to implement async abstract base classes? Or maybe there is already something in Python for this, just I don't know about it?

Answer (score 2):

What I wanted is impossible because language syntax is missing for it.

There is syntax for `await some_map["key"]` or `await some_map.get("key", default_value)` but it will never work for these:

```
del some_map["key"] # del is a keyword, cannot await
some_map["key"] = value # assignment is a syntax, but there is no syntax to await for it
```

So basically, what I want is not possible because syntax is missing from the language. I must implement this with regular methods, and possibly implement some of the dunder methods that can be used with currently available syntax - but even then it might be a bad idea, because IDEs and code inspector programs will probably never complain about missing awaits and introduce bugs. For example, when get() is an async method, then a code inspector may warn about this:

```
# warning: # some_dict.get() was never awaited for
return some_dict.get("key")
```

However, it will never complain about this:

```
# this is not a method call, no warning issued
return some_dict["key"]
```